# Connecting a 12V USB device to Pi

Tags: usb, usb-power, rfid

I'm planning to use a long range USB RFID reader (12V) [like this](http://joneytechnology.en.made-in-china.com/product/ABknhfcvXrWw/China-125kHz-Em-Middle-Range-1m-RFID-Reader.html) with Pi. As Pi USB can supply only 5V, how can I connect it to Pi USB, if it is not external powered..??

Comment: The device you linked to is not a USB RFID reader.  According to the specs the interface is "Wiegand 26/34,RS485/232"

Comment: Ya,sorry, my mistake...I mean to use an USB powered but gives a reading range like the above mentioned reader, around 1 meter.

Answer (score 1):

A switching step-up converter could be used to provide a higher voltage (12V) from a given lower voltage (5V). Be sure that the 5V power supply of the RPi can provide high enough a current though to drive that additional load.

ElectricalEngineering.SE might however be better suited to help on that matter and recommend a circuitry for that need. If you just want to buy some ready-to-use gagdet look out for "DC DC Step Up Converter".

Comment: Thanks for that step up converters...
Pi B+ gives 1.2A for USBs (distributed over 4 ports), so I suppose that will be good enough.